# Wrong I18n locale is loaded randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

Sometimes instead of expected Japanese language config, the English config is being loaded, which actually doesn't exist and isn't set anywhere neither as a default_locale nor as a fallback one.

The problem is that it happens occasionally/randomly and was impossible to replicate before, but today it started occurring really often. That is, just by staying on the same page and pressing F5 resulted on average in about 50/50% of occurrences of EN/JAP locales (no pattern, just random).
The thing is that the site DOESN'T even have the ENG locale implemented at all, so when it tries to load ENG locale it fails with an understandable error:

```
ERROR -- : .... translation missing: en.some_translation...
```

And this is the only error occurring.

But it SHOULD NOT be even attempting to load ENG locale.
The locale is firmly set in application.rb:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :ja
config.i18n.locale = :ja
```

production.rb shouldn't be overwriting this setting as it only contains:

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = false
```

It happens only in production.
"god restart app_name" fixes it for some time, but it seems like it occurs more as the time passes by, but I can't say for sure about it.
The error that occurs in ENG locale seems to be the same if when I set default_locale to:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
```

But I have grepped my application code for the "default_locale" and couldn't find any code that changes it. Could some gem be a culprit?

Rails version: 4.2.7.1
I18n vesrion: 0.7.0

Would much appreciate any hint at this point.

Comment: This is obviously a complete guess, since I don't have access to any of your source code... But maybe you have some code in your application (e.g. in a gem) that's changing global state with `I18n.locale = :en` -- and then since your production server has multiple processes, only some of these get stuck in the alternate locale.

Comment: It is possible that you didn't properly set the default locale. I have used I18n in so many apps and never experienced this issue. Do you have a `set_locale` method in your application controller? with `before_action :set_locale` , this will probably be a `before_filter` in rails 4.

Comment: @TomLord
Thanks for the suggestion! That's the line I'm currently investigating for the lack of other clues. I have no such code in the project itself, but gems are a possibility, however the problem is that I have about 230 gems in my bundle...

Comment: @mayorsanmayor
Thanks for the comment! However I don't thinks this is the case, since the project is actually a working one and normally there are no problems with the (Japanese) locale whatsoever. But on some very rare occasions (normally) it would try to load ENG for some reason.
As for application controller, I don't use the `set_locale` method there, but I set locale in **/config/application.rb** which I think should be sufficient normally...

Answer (score 0):

I have figured the reason why `:en` locale was loading.

The `config.i18n.fallbacks` was actually set to `true` later in code.
And since the `config.i18n.available_locales` wasn't set in **application.rb** explicitly, `I18n` gem had `:en` locale included there and when the `:ja` locale, which was set in `config.i18n.locale` and `config.i18n.default_locale` failed to load (for reason yet unknown), it tried to fallback to `:en` locale which led to the problem.

Unfortunately, still no idea why would `:js` locale fail to load, but I guess that's entirely another question.

Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

I happened same issue.
I have solved it and figured out  that I set "set_scale" function too as before_action on another controller  other than applicaton_controller as a mistake.